# Displacement outcome varies from face to face despite having the normals face the same direction

Tags: materials, node-editor, normals, displacement

I've had this problem multiple times now in Blender 2.93.2. I apply an image for displacement purposes in the node editor, but some faces (they are in an about 90 degree angle to the working ones, it seems) just flip the strength from positive to negative (or the other way around), but when I check the normals, they all face the same direction. Flipping the ones, that display the displacement wrongly, does solve the problem, but is a lot of work. Does anyone know, what causes this and what the solution is?

Thanks a lot in advance!

File: pasteall.org/blend/2573cad75176491780d3e1d12186c59d

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I recreated the problem with a very basic model: https://pasteall.org/blend/2573cad75176491780d3e1d12186c59d

Comment: From what I know you can't use the Displacement input of the Material Output this way, you need to be in Cycles, you need to put a Displacement node, you need to go into Material > Settings > Displacement > Displacement Only, and you need ti subdivide your object. Actually what you probably want to do is to plug your texture into the Height input of a Bump node that you plug into the Normal of your Principled BSDF

Comment: Also, in bump maps, black is for hollows, white is for bumps, here your photo has white mortar, which makes it look like bump, maybe invert the colors

Comment: @moonboots With the original file I was in cycles and had the colours inverted (forgot to change that in the shared file) and I've always used the nodes that way and never had a problem until one month ago. Also I want to bake a normal map from the displacement later on, so I can't use the bump node.

Comment: Ok I didn't know you could use the Displacement input as the equivalent of a Bump node. But I can't see any inconsistency here, here is what it gives if I move the light: https://zupimages.net/up/22/24/icas.jpg ... The only problem I see is that the mortar makes bumps instead of hollow, but as I said the mortar is white in your original picture, if you want the opposite, use a Color > Invert. If I haven't understood the question correctly, maybe highlight the problem on a screenshot?

Comment: @moonboots Ok, so it seems the problem is with my computer or blender version or whatever. Yours really looks completely normal. I guess, I'll download Blender again and see if it works after that. Thanks a lot by the way!